# Python gRPC - " This class is part of an EXPERIMENTAL API."

Tags: python, grpc

I used the proto file from the official tutorial https://grpc.io/docs/languages/python/quickstart/.

```proto
// The greeting service definition.
syntax = "proto3";

service Greeter {
    // Sends a greeting
    rpc SayHello (HelloRequest) returns (HelloReply) {}
    // Sends another greeting
    rpc SayHelloAgain (HelloRequest) returns (HelloReply) {}
  }
  
  // The request message containing the user's name.
  message HelloRequest {
    string name = 1;
  }
  
  // The response message containing the greetings
  message HelloReply {
    string message = 1;
  }
```

And generated the code by using the command.

```
py -m grpc_tools.protoc -I. --python_out=. --grpc_python_out=. ./*.proto
```

The code generated like this, I fold the details
[image]

I know the "Stub" is for the client, and the "Servicer" is for the server.
But what's the purpose of the class marked with "This class is part of an EXPERIMENTAL API"?

I searched a lot, but nothing mentions it.

Answer (score 1):

I think that is because it uses `grpc.experimental.unary_unary` as a return type for some of its methods. Look at the relevant "_pb2_grpc.py" file, which was generated from proto mentioned by you.